# GraphQL query with fragments only retrieving the last fragment data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, gql

In a React app using Apollo, I've set up a GraphGL query to be called in a useQuery hook at any component in the app. I've set it up the way the backend has set it up with fragments. The call works fine in Insomnia but in my app, the last fragment overwrites all the other fragment data. So the query looks like this:

```
export const GET_CHILD_MENUS = gql`
  fragment item on IndexedItem {
    id
    title
  }

  fragment childMenus on Menus {
    schoolGrades {
      ...item
    }
    languageAbilities {
      ...item
    }
    concerns {
      ...item
    }
    diagnoses {
      ...item
    }
  }

  query AddChildMenus_v1 {
    menus {
      ...childMenus
    }
  }
`
```

and on a useQuery call like:

```
const { data } = useQuery<any>(GET_CHILD_MENUS)
```

The result is that every field gets the `diagnoses` array of data:

```
menus: 
 concerns: <diagnoses data>
 languageAbilities: <diagnoses data>
 schoolGrades: <diagnoses data>
 diagnoses: <diagnoses data>
```

Any ideas why this is occurring?

Comment: Does it happen regardless of the position of `diagnoses` field?

Comment: No. If I were to move `schoolGrades` to the bottom, all the data would be that.